# Add custom property in NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am new to Objective C in general.

I am creating a class which listens for a notification

In that notification, I intend to have it as NSdictionary with two key value pairs

```
// eventType -> determine which value to change
// value -> value which needs to be changed -> can be string, dynamic object and Bool


TS equivalent would 

interface event {
 eventType: string 
 value: any
}
```

in a.h, I currently have

```
- (void)initMessageEmit {
    NSLog(@" Initialize observers ");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
            name:@"selfParticipantNotification"
            object:nil];
}
```

and empty `receive notification`

```
- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
```

I would like to have my recieveNotification as this

```
- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"selfParticipantNotification"]) {
        NSDictionary *event = notification.event;
        if (![event value]) {
            if ([[event eventType] isEqualToString:@"enabled"]) {
                [self enabled:event.value]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above, if eventType value is `enabled`, I call a method `enabled` and update a property value.

`value` here could be anything -> NSString/NSDictionary/Bool and is/should be passed by `postNotificationName`

**Question**: How can I send data with NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `object` parameter to post anything with the notification like following.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
postNotificationName:@"selfParticipantNotification"
              object:@{@"key":@"value"}];
```

While receving the notification, you can read this value like following.

```
 (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"selfParticipantNotification"]) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary*)notification.object;
        // Do something with dictionary
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, I have updated the question, can you please go through it again?

Comment: I have used `NSDictionary` as an object in my example. You can use any object (your custom class event as you want) in it's place. Pass your object while posting the notification & read the same via `(Event*)notification.object` if your object's class is called `Event` for example.

Comment: @anny123 There was a mistake in the answer for the code of `postNotificationName` earlier, I have fixed that now, please review.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out in a bit and let you know if this works. 
Again, Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: Tarun, when I do `BOOL *enabled = notification.userInfo[@"value"];` it gives this **error** `Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'BOOL *' (aka 'bool *') is disallowed with ARC`. it also gives following warning `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'BOOL *' (aka 'bool *') with an expression of type 'id _Nullable'`. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: `BOOL`  is not an object, you can pass it via `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` from the post AND read it as `[(NSNumber*)notification.object boolValue]` on the receive side.